# Are high-density moons plausible beyond the frost line?

Tags: science-based, moons

I have 3 gas giants in my system, 5.23, 10.97 and 15.14 AU respectively from a G3V star with .97 solar luminosity.  Would the satellites of these worlds start higher density (rock-ice mix) and progressively become more icy the further out from the sun?  OR, is it realistic to have some of the satellites (primarily concerned about the major moons) have some higher densities at the farther distances?
I would like to have a way to plausibly explain it if the latter is true.  I know Triton has a higher density than Iapetus does.

Edit:  I'm not expecting any exoplanet specialists to read/critique what I've done, esp. since I'm handwaving the space travel part of it. BUT, me being me, I do want this to be reasonably accurate/grounded in reality (yes, go ahead and giggle at the irony of the statement). I guess I get too hung up on the minutiae to see the big picture at times. (Long winded way of saying, yes, I know, and thank you!)

Comment: Remember that as a worldbuilder anything you want to be possible in your world will be. Just say "In my world X is possible". Are you expecting exoplanet specialists to be grading your world? Does it really matter if they say "In the real world that is unlikely?" if you have written a compelling story a highly detailed analysis of background detail is an indication that they couldn't get the story out of their head. What exactly are you looking for from us? Permission to have cool things? You have my blessing. Go forth and write without fear of unrealistic worlds.

Comment: We understand the all-too-human desire to be as "realistic" as possible, but don't let that drive get in the way of a good story - especially when you're talking about stuff in space. We're constantly discovering things that surprise us. To be honest, most "is X realistic?" questions have more in common with "can I have your permission to use this idea?" than "is this idea factual?" Remember, our stated purpose ([help/on-topic]) is to help people build *imaginary worlds.* Reality is over-rated.

Comment: It's actually going to be (hopefully) like the book National Geographic Picture Atlas of Our Universe.  So, no real story to tell, just maps, maps, and more maps...plus some infographic type stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Definitely

Even if you can find some correlation between moon densities with the distance from the Sun you can find multiple reasons as to why a planet can have a denser moon than the nearest planets to the sun. In our system Titania is denser than Enceladus, Triton is denser than Titan or Ganymede etc..

One of the best choice if you want to justify that easily and plausibly (for an exotic-composed planet, let's say mainly composed of metal for example) is the gravitational catch. Not hard to believe at all.
Another solution is to refering to a great migration of the planets in your system, with some moons "created" along the migration from the inner system to the outer
But you don't even have to justify it. The Jupiter's moons diversity is enough to understand moons systems don't have to share the same characteristics.